# Facebook API for educational purposes

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I want to use the facebook Login for a school project.
Apart from his/her public profile, I also need to get his/her likes. 
The only way facebook lets you do that, is by submitting a review form in which I have to enter information that I don't know. I can't even fill out the URL of my website since I only host it locally.

Is there a way that you can access those permissions without having to submit those review forms for educational purposes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to use the extended permissions even without Login Review, but only if

> People listed in the Roles section of your App Dashboard - including Admins, Developers and Testers - can grant any permission without review. If only people in these Roles will use your app, you don't need to submit it for Login Review.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#login_review